# How to get data attribute with "onclick" method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following two "div" with "anchor" tag and i want to get "attribute" with "onclick" function,Here is my html code

```
<div class="upvote_dm">
<a class="pr_vote_up '.$clssup.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="1" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Up'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#"  data-id="10" onclick="return AddFeedVotes()"></a>
<span id="UpVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultUpVotes.'</span>
</div>
                   
<div class="downvote_dm">
<a class="pr_vote_down '.$clssdown.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="0" data-status="Down'.$FeedId.'" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Down'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#" data-id="10" onclick="return AddFeedVotes()"></a>
<span id="DownVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultDownVotes.'</span>
</div>
```

Now i am trying to get attribute with following way but showing me "Undefine",Where i am wrong ?

```
<script>
       function AddFeedVotes()
            {
                var vote = $(this).data('datac');
                var type = $(this).data('type');
                var flagid = $(this).data('flagid');
                            
                alert(vote);
                alert(type);
                 alert(flagid);    
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you use "return AddFeedVotes()" onclick? Why not just "AddFeedVotes()"?

Comment: And you don't need to use jquery. You can just type: `this.dataset.datac`

Comment: @МихаилТихонов: can you write "right" code so i can check your code

Comment: If you are using Jquery, why don't you use `.on('click', .... )`?

Comment: @Gert B: i tried but with in that case "click" was working more than one time instead of "only one" , thats why i am trying with some different way

Comment: if it triggers multiple times, your selector is not correct I guess. Using onclick is not recommended

Comment: What did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which of the lines throws that error, and what is the **exact** error message you are facing?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try native `javascript`

```js
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", event => {
  console.log(event.target.dataset.a)
})
```

```html
<button data-a="111111" id="btn">button</button>
```

Comment: how to use multiple elements.

Comment: Multiple elements can try event delegation based on event bubbling

Answer (score 1):

So main problem is that onclick="return AddFeedVotes()" you don't put this argument: `return AddFeedVotes(this)`, because `this` in that context is element.

Html:

```html
<div class="upvote_dm">
<a class="pr_vote_up '.$clssup.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="1" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Up'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#"  data-id="10" onclick="return AddFeedVotes(this)"></a>
<span id="UpVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultUpVotes.'</span>
</div>
                   
<div class="downvote_dm">
<a class="pr_vote_down '.$clssdown.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="0" data-status="Down'.$FeedId.'" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Down'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#" data-id="10" onclick="return AddFeedVotes(this)"></a>
<span id="DownVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultDownVotes.'</span>
</div>
```

Here just removed jquery, because native way more lighter.

JS:

```js
function AddFeedVotes(e)
{
  let vote = e.dataset.datac;
  let type = e.dataset.type;
  let flagid = e.dataset.flagid;
                            
  alert(vote);
  alert(type);
  alert(flagid);    
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @silentwasd: i want to send more attribute but unable to send,How i can send "datacw" and "id" also ?

Comment: @sheetalbaveja same way: `let datacw = e.dataset.datacw; let id = e.dataset.id;`

Answer (score 1):

**You haven't linked your inline calling of the function with the specific element, and therefore cannot reference the `data` attributes.**

You can add a click event using a new class as I have done below, if you add `.vote` to your links then add a click event to them all using  `jquery`.

```
$("a.vote").click( function() {
   // code goes here
});
```

You will need to distinguish up or down votes later in your code, but could use:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('pr_vote_down')) {
   // down vote code
} else {
   // up vote code
}
```

---

```js
// Add click event to all a tags with class vote
$("a.vote").click(function() {

  // No you can use $(this) as you have linked the function to the specific element rather than calling it in the absract.
  var vote = $(this).data('datac');
  var type = $(this).data('type');
  var flagid = $(this).data('flagid');

  // Check if the clicked link has the down vote class
  if ($(this).hasClass('pr_vote_down')) {
    // down vote code
    alert("down vote");
  } else {
    // up vote code
    alert("up vote");
  }

  alert(vote);
  alert(type);
  alert(flagid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upvote_dm">
  <a class="pr_vote_up vote '.$clssup.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="1" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Up '.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#" data-id="10">Up Vote</a>
  <span id="UpVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultUpVotes.'</span>
</div>

<div class="downvote_dm">
  <a class="pr_vote_down vote '.$clssdown.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="0" data-status="Down'.$FeedId.'" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Down '.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#" data-id="10">Down Vote</a>
  <span id="DownVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultDownVotes.'</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you didn't added anything for a tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="upvote_dm">
        <a  id="upVote" class="pr_vote_up '.$clssup.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="1" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Up'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#"  data-id="10" onclick="return AddFeedVotes()">Up vote</a>
        <span>'.$DefaultUpVotes.'</span>
    </div>

    <div class="downvote_dm">
        <a id="downVote" class="pr_vote_down '.$clssdown.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="0" data-status="Down'.$FeedId.'" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Down'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#" data-id="10" >Down vote</a>
        <span >'.$DefaultDownVotes.'</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#upVote, #downVote').click(function(event) {
        var vote = $(this).data('datac');
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        var flagid = $(this).data('flagid');

        alert(vote);
        alert(type);
        alert(flagid);  
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First place your span in the anchor tag

```js
$('a[data-type="feed"]').click(function(event) {
    var vote = $(this).data('datac');
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    var flagid = $(this).data('flagid');

    alert(vote);
    alert(type);
    alert(flagid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upvote_dm">
<a class="pr_vote_up '.$clssup.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="1" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Up'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#"  data-id="10"><span id="UpVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultUpVotes.'</span></a>

</div>
                   
<div class="downvote_dm">
<a class="pr_vote_down '.$clssdown.' btnsnew '.$FeedId.'" data-datac="0" data-status="Down'.$FeedId.'" data-flagid='.$FeedId.' id=Down'.$FeedId.' data-type="feed" data-datacw='.$UserWalletAddress.' href="#" data-id="10" ><span id="DownVoteCount'.$FeedId.'">'.$DefaultDownVotes.'</span></a>

</div>
```